# Avoiding the garbage collection

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243682/944430

> And then there is coding: use unboxed types (no GC), minimize lazy structure allocation. Keep long lived data around in packed form. Test and benchmark.

1.) What are unboxed types? I am pretty sure he is speaking about data types, something like `Just x` or `IO y` (boxed). But what about newtypes? If I understood it correctly, newtype has no overhead at all and therefore shouldn't count as a boxed type?

2.) What does he mean by `Keep long lived data around in packed form.`?

3.) What else can I do to prevent GC pauses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 .
Unboxed types are the primitives in Haskell. For example, `Int` is defined as: `data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#` (for the GHC compiler). The trailing `#` symbol is used to indicate primitives (this is only convention). Primitives don't really exist in Haskell. You can't define additional primitives. When they appear in code, the compiler is responsible for translating them to 'real' function calls (functions can be primitives too) and datatypes.

Yes, newtype does not 'box' a type additionally. But you can't have a newtype containing a primitive - `newtype Int2 = Int2 Int#` is invalid while `data Int2 = Int2 Int#` is fine.

The main difference between primitive and boxed types in the context of the question you linked is how they are represented in memory. A primitive type means there are no pointers to follow. A pointer to an `Int#` *must* point to the value of the number, whereas a pointer to an `Int` may point to a thunk which points to a thunk ... etc. Note that this means that primitives are always strict. If you believe this will be an issue, use the `UNPACK` pragma, which removes any 'intermediate' boxing. That is,

```
data D = D (Int, Int)
```

is stored as a pointer (D) to a pointer (the tuple) to a block of memory containing two pointers (Ints) which each point to an actual `Int#`. However,

```
data D = D {-# UNPACK #-} !(Int, Int)
```

is stored as a pointer (D) to two `Int`s, thereby removing one level of boxing. Note the `!`. This indicates that that field is strict and is required for `UNPACK`.

2 . Any data which is going to be called with polymorphic functions should be kept packed, as unpacked data passed to polymorphic functions will be repacked anyways (introducing unnecessary overhead). The reasoning behind keeping long-lived data packed is that it is more likely to be used in an intermediate datatype or function which will require repacking, while this is easier to control with short-lived data which is only passed to a few functions before being garbage collected.

3 . In 99% of cases, you won't have issues with garbage collector pauses. In general, there aren't things you can do to guarantee the GC will not pause. The only suggestion I have is, don't try to reinvent the wheel. There are libraries designed for high-performance computations with large amounts of data (repa, vector, etc). If you try to implement it yourself, chances are, they did it better!

Comment: Your example isn't quite right, it will unbox the tuple but the individual `Int`s will be boxed.  If you want two primitive `Int#`s it's necessary to use `data D = D {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int` (or -funbox-strict-fields).

Answer (score 2):

If you define `data Int2 = Int`, You could think of `Int#` being unboxed, plain `Int` being boxed and `Int2` as "double boxed". Is you used `newtype` instead of `data`, it would have avoided one indirection. But `Int` itself is still boxed. Therefore  `Int2` is boxed too.

As for [packed form](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html), without going into to much details, it intuitively is similar to this kind of C-code.

```
struct PackedCoordinate {
   int x;
   int y;
}

struct UnpackedCoordinate {
   int *x;
   int *y;
}
```

I'm not sure why he suggested long lived data to be in packed form. Anyhow, it seems from the documentation I linked to that one should be careful using the `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragma, because if you're unlucky, GHC might need to repack it's values before function calls, making it allocating more memory than it would if it wasn't unpacked to begin with.

In order to avoid garbage collections. I think you should approach this as anything else related to profiling: Find the bottle-neck in your program and then work from there.

---

PS. Please comment on anything I happen to be incorrect about. :)

Comment: This link should explain a lot more about unboxed types and their limitations -> http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/primitives.html