# GHC per thread GC strategy

Tags: multithreading, haskell, memory, garbage-collection, ghc

I have a [Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) api server which constructs an [Elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org) query, fetches results from [ES](http://elasticsearch.org) and renders the json.

In comparison to other servers like [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org) and [Gin](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/), I'm getting higher CPU utilization and throughput for serving [ES](http://elasticsearch.org) responses by using [BloodHound](https://github.com/bitemyapp/bloodhound) but [Gin](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/) and [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org) were magnitudes better than [Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) in memory efficiency.

Stats for Scotty

```
 wrk -t30 -c100 -d30s "http://localhost:3000/filters?apid=1&hfa=true"
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:3000/filters?apid=1&hfa=true
  30 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   192.04ms  305.45ms   1.95s    83.06%
    Req/Sec   133.42    118.21     1.37k    75.54%
  68669 requests in 30.10s, 19.97MB read
Requests/sec:   2281.51
Transfer/sec:    679.28KB
```

These stats are on my Mac having GHC 7.10.1 installed

Processor info 2.5GHx i5
Memory info 8GB 1600 Mhz DDR3

I am quite impressed by lightweight thread based concurrency of GHC but memory efficiency remains a big concern.

Profiling memory usage yielded me the following stats

```
    39,222,354,072 bytes allocated in the heap
     277,239,312 bytes copied during GC
     522,218,848 bytes maximum residency (14 sample(s))
         761,408 bytes maximum slop
            1124 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       373 colls,   373 par    2.802s   0.978s     0.0026s    0.0150s
  Gen  1        14 colls,    13 par    0.534s   0.166s     0.0119s    0.0253s

  Parallel GC work balance: 42.38% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 18 (1 bound, 17 peak workers (17 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  MUT     time   31.425s  ( 36.161s elapsed)
  GC      time    3.337s  (  1.144s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  Total   time   34.765s  ( 37.314s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,248,117,604 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  90.4% of total user, 84.2% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 27215
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 8919
gen[1].sync: 30902
```

[Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org) never took more than 150 MB, while [Gin](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/) took much lower memory.

I believe that GHC uses mark and sweep strategy for GC. I also believe it would have been better to use per thread incremental GC strategy akin to Erlang VM for better memory efficiency.

And by interpreting Don Stewart's answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236238/current-state-of-haskell-soft-real-time) there must be some way to change the GC strategy in GHC.

I also noted that the memory usage remained stable and pretty low when the concurrency level was low, so I think memory usage booms up only when concurrency is pretty high.

Any ideas/pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: What's your actual *question*? How to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Broadly yes. More specifically if I could find a way to enable per thread GC strategy in GHC.

Comment: I was under the impression that recent versions of GHC *already* do per-thread GC, but I may be wrong about that...

Comment: I believe GHC uses a mark and sweep strategy. It uses a generational mechanism to manage memory. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's definitely generational, and I believe it's mark/sweep. However, I was under the impression that the youngest generation is per-core. I will see if I can find an actual reference for that though.

Comment: For a web server like use cases where a thread is spawned for every request, per thread memory cleanup strategy seems to be a reasonable strategy.

Answer (score 1):

http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/local-gc.pdf

This paper by Simon Marlow describes per-thread local heaps, and claims that this was implemented in GHC. It's dated 2011. I can't be sure if this is what the current version of GHC actually does (i.e., did this go into the release version of GHC, is it still the current status quo, etc.), but it seems my recollection wasn't completely made up.

I will also point out the section of the GHC manual that explains the settings you can twiddle to adjust the garbage collector:

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-gc

In particular, by default GHC uses a 2-space collector, but adding the `-c` RTS option makes it use a slightly slower 1-space collector, which should eat less RAM. (I'm entirely unclear which generation(s) this information applies to.)

I get the impression Simon Marlow is the guy who does most of the RTS stuff (including the garbage collector), so if you can find him on IRC, he's the guy to ask if you want the direct truth...